# Internet Explorer: how do I refresh html layout programmatically?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I have Active-X component on HTML page with long-run method (Process) that fires callback to javascript.

```
    activex.Process(
        function (message) {
            // alert(message);  --> message box appears, everything ok 
            $("#panel").text(message);   // panel doesn't refreshed!
        }
    }

<div id="panel" >
        active-x messages should be here! 
</div>
```

Callbacks fire ok (I can see messagebox'es) but panel doesn't refreshed until Process method returns.

May I force panel to be refreshed or shall I fire callbacks from another thread?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling `activex.Process()` from JavaScript, then the browser blocks until the JS function returns.

Try to create a new thread in `Process()` and return immediately. That should "unlock" your browser. IE's JavaScript engine should properly synchronize the callback code when you invoke it from your new thread.